# Is the source code to Common Interpreted Language compiler located within the CLR in .NET

Tags: .net, visual-studio, frameworks, cil

I am aware that .NET compliant source code is first compiled to CIL and then to native code by the JIT compiler within the CLR but I was wondering whether the first compilation is made within the CLR or the Visual Studio environment by a separate compiler.

Comment: Usually, languages like C#, F#, VB.NET, C++/CLI and many others that have been ported to .NET have a separate compiler to generate the CIL.  It is not the only way to generate CIL, Reflection.Emit and tools like Tlbimp.exe do it as well.

Comment: Thanks. So the separate compiler is part of a Visual Studio package?

Comment: Compilers for each languages are considered separate components (from different vendors). Visual Studio ships with C#/VB.NET/F#/C++ compilers, but you can get other third party compilers.

Comment: Great thanks. That clarified things. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The language specific compiler transforms the code into IL (or CIL, or MSIL) and packages it as a .dll or .exe file/s, which is ultimately executed by the CLR.**

The below image illustrates the steps that are performed in order for your code to be executed.

If you want, you can use [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy#ilspy) or what Microsoft delivers as part of the .NET framework ([ILDasm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler)) to disassemble the .dll or .exe and view the IL code. (Those are not the only disassemblers, but they are free)

[image]